# How can I add a default billing title to WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently looking for a hook, to add a default billing title to the `billing_title` select to the WooCommerce `checkout` and `change-address` setting at the MyAccount page.

It should be something like `Please select salutation` and should be a required field. This field comes from the WooCommerce Germanized plugin and is a required field in Germany. Because of this there is no documentation about this (sadly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
/**
 * Add billing title default selection value
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gzd_title_options', 'add_new_billing_title', 10, 1 );
function add_new_billing_title( $titles ) {
    array_unshift( $titles, 'Bitte auswählen' );

    return $titles;
}
```

I'm using `array_unshift` to add the default **Please select** value in German as first element in the select.